# Have roots of $z^3+|a|z^2+|b|z+|c|$ module $1$ if roots of $z^3+az^2+bz+c$ have module $1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{C}$ and for any root $\alpha$ of polynomial $z^3+az^2+bz+c$, $|\alpha |=1$.

Prove that for any root $\beta$ of polynomial $z^3+|a|z^2+|b|z+|c|$, $|\beta |=1$.

My try so far:

Let's suppose $z_1, z_2, z_3$ are roots of $z^3+az^2+bz+c$, by Vieta's formula I know that

$$a=-(z_1+z_2+z_3)$$

$$b=z_1z_2+z_2z_3+z_1z_3$$

$$c=-z_1z_2z_3$$

and substituing in $z^3+|a|z^2+|b|z+|c|$ I have that

$$z^3+|z_1+z_2+z_3|z^2+|z_1z_2+z_2z_3+z_1z_3|+|z_1z_2z_3|\le z^3+3z^2+3z+1=(z+1)^3$$

I guess it's a good thing getting to a polynomial as $(z+1)^3$ because its roots have module $1$, but I don't see a clear way to go. Any idea?

Edit:

Assuming $\beta =e^{i\theta}\alpha$ and substituing in the polynomial then I get

$$e^{3i\theta}\alpha^3+|a|e^{2i\theta}\alpha^2+|b|e^{i\theta}\alpha+|c|$$

and have to prove this is $0$, but don't know how to follow

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't push through the approach I previously mentioned in my hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $\bar cz^3+\bar b z^2+\bar a +1$ has the same roots as the original polynomial (has roots $1/\bar w=w$) so there is $k$ st $\bar c =k, \bar b=ka, \bar a=kb, 1=kc$ so $k=1/c, |c|=1=|k|$ so $|a|=|b|=q\le 3$ and then the new equation is $z^3+qz^2+qz+1=(z+1)(z^2+(q-1)z+1)=0$ and the quadratic has discriminant at most $0$ since $-1\le q-1\le 2$ so it either has two complex conjugate roots of modulus $1$ or a double root at $-1$ so in any case all roots of modulus one too

Comment: Ah, showing $|a|=|b|$ is key, which can be done directly too.

Comment: @Calvin yes using that $w_1w_2=1/w_3=\bar w_3$ we can show $|a|=|b|$ too though ultimately it's same thing with the above

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes, using OP's first idea (Vieta), directly $|a|^2 = 3 + z_1 \bar{z_2} +  \cdots$ and $|b|^2 = 3 + z_1\bar{z_2} + \cdots$ (only using $|z_1| = |z_2| = |z_3| = 1$) which are equal. (Already upvoted yesterday).